# django model formset instances, identifying each form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This is my model

```
class Business(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    mail_address = models.ForeignKey(Address,related_name="mailing_address")
```

my address model

```
class Address(models.Model):
   address_line1 = models.CharField("Address line 1", max_length = 45)
   address_line2 = models.CharField("Address line 2", max_length = 45, blank = True)
   city = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False) 
   state = USStateField()
   postal_code = USZipCodeField()
```

im trying to write a view where the user enters the business and address info at the same time 
i am trying to use a model formset for users to fill in business and mailing addresses
however I want to make it such that the user can leave the mailing address section blank if it is the same as business address.

how do i achieve this since in my address model nothing can be left blank...

further if a user wants to edit it how do i render the formset with different instances?

Comment: You already answered your question: You must allow at least one of the address FKs be blank in the *model*. You can handle validation in the form.

Comment: you mean in the business model?

Comment: what would my formset look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove the mail_adress Foreign Key in the Buisness Model
2. add a normal CharField for the mailing list
3. dont make this charfield required.

later you can check whether there is a mailing adress or not and use it appropiately.

```
If mailing_adress:
    do stuff
else:
    use buisness.address
```